# React Outlook Add-in interface bug

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Our organization has an Outlook add-in written in React. Not so long ago, a bug appeared when you open the letter completely and open the taskpane setting, part of the letter management interface freezes in the same place, that is, overlapping part of the taskpane. Applicable only to Windows clients, no problem was noticed on macbooks.

Also, this bug does not happen all the time, but periodically.

Is there any solution to this problem? Is it possible to change some parameters in the manifest?

[image: example interface bug]

I changed the values of the "RequestedWidth" manifest attribute, set my html styles to 100% and fixed values in pixels.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, the code is executed in Outlook, also on react, it will be difficult for me to provide some minimum acceptable working option. I can provide the add-in manifest, but I don't know how much it will help you.

The bug is clearly related specifically to the Outlook application, since taskpane opens a separate window, which should contain only my components, and not part of the email interface, as can be seen in the screenshot.